# Play! framework 2.4.x - lifecycle of injected components

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection

I'm using Play! framework and I have a problem with a component injected in this controller:

```
public class Admin extends Controller {

    @Inject
    MenuManager menuManager;

    public Result adminHome(){
        return ok(views.html.admin_area.adminHome.render(menuManager.menuVoices()));
    }
}
```

The action adminHome show the homepage of my web application and I'm injecting `menuManager` component as a service.

This is the code for MenuManager class:

```
public class MenuManager {

        private ArrayList<String> voices;

        public MenuManager(){
            voices = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        public List<String> menuVoices(){

            voices.add("Voice_1");
            voices.add("Voice_2");
            voices.add("Voice_3");

            return voices;
        }
    }
```

The view I'm going to render is this:

```
@(menuVoices: List[String])


<div>

    @for(voice <- menuVoices){
        <div>@voice</div>
    }

</div>
```

I can't understand the lifecycle of the injected object: menuManager.

I'll try to explain the problem. When I load the homepage I see the menu with three voices. If I reaload the page I see three more voices, this happen each time I reload the page after the first time. This happen because when I call the action adminHome() the object menuManager doesn't get re-instanced so I add the same three voices to the list before render it.
A solution to this problem could be recreate the list each time I create the menu, in the method `menuVoices` but I don't know if this is the right way to proceed.

There is a way to force the controller to re-instance the object each time I call the action without modifying the class MenuManager? So, let's say, can I shorten the lifecycle of this object?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you not noticed `MenuManager`  class with `@Singleton` annotation?..

Comment: Yea, I've done it but the result is the same :(

Comment: Dit you check that controller instance is unique per request?
Play 2.4?

Comment: No, how can I do that??

Comment: `System.out.println(this.toString());` in your adminHome() action.
In console you will see different object hashCode `@7ba0d59f` for each request.

Comment: And how do you configure an implementation of your MenuManager? Do you use @ImplementedBy or bind().to()?..

Comment: I don't configure an implementation for the menu manager because MenuManager is just a class and not an interface.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Play controllers are singletons, as explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34867199/4600

Because of that, your `MenuManager` is injected just once and reused each request. Also, since you populate the menu list each time the method `menuVoices` is called, the list of itens will grow each time you call that method at the same instance of `MenuManager`. If you rewrite your service like the following, it will works as expected:

```
public class MenuManager {

    private List<String> voices = Arrays.asList(
        "Voice_1",
        "Voice_2",
        "Voice_3"
    );

    public List<String> menuVoices() {
        return voices;
    }
}
```