# Play 2.5.X: method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm new to PlayFramework.

Please give me a sample how to access Configuration parameters from my view. I'm using PlayFramework 2.5.3

Old way (@current is deprecated):

```
@current.configuration.getString("environment.param")
```

New way (as far as I understand, Configuration should be injected):

I know how to access it from controller.

```
@Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi, configuration: Configuration)
```

How do I use it from my view?

Comment: If you need this only in one or two places, you can provide the configuration as a parameter to your view.

Comment: DI in twirl templates will come soon hopefully: https://github.com/playframework/twirl/pull/100

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly there isn't much you can do about it. It is just how it is when DI was introduced to Play, not much was discussed in regard to templates. One possible solution could be:

1. Inject `Configuration` in controller
2. Send it as `implicit` to your view/template

   ```
   class Application @Inject() (implicit val config: Configuration) extends Controller {

       def index = Action {
           Ok(views.html.index("foo"))
       }
   }
   ```

And your template will look like:

```
@(myParam1: Any)(implicit config: Configuration)
<h2>Some HTML here @myParam1 @config.getString("environment.param")</h2>
```

---

*I am totally aware that this somehow defeats the purpose of DI but this is just how it is right now.*

Comment: Thanks! It works. My solution was the same as yours, but I didn't add implicit lazy val config = configuration. And that's why I got errors.

Comment: You could change this to `class Application @Inject() (implicit val config: Configuration) ..` and it would have the same effect, then you could remove the redundant `implicit lazy val config = configuration`

Comment: can you explain how does it defeat the purpose of DI?

Comment: Corrected the answer as suggested by m-z, indeed a cleaner solution. @Łukasz well with parameters you actually **have to** provide the configuration to the template - which is not what is DI about. In DI we want the template to say *"Give me the configuration"* instead of providing it

Comment: Isn't DI about that object does not create its dependencies, but they are created outside and delivered through for example constructor. The template says give me the configuration by saying, to call me you need to pass in configuration. Same goes for controller, it gets the dependency through a constructor. No matter if Guice injects it, or you inject it in the code it's still DI. At least this is how I understand DI.

Comment: Well yeah you could argue that as long "someone" injects something, then it is DI. But from my point of view DI is when Guice (or similar) takes care of injecting the needed dependency - so that I only specify what I need but never have to provide it myself.

Comment: Are you sure that you want whole config in view ? Maybe you can pass single variable from config.

Comment: Sure, you can do this, it is just that the OP did not specify this precisely. But nothing stops you from extracting the needed information in the controller and pass only that to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there might be changes in 2.6.x or twirl 1.2.0

https://github.com/playframework/twirl/pull/100

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#Template-constructor

Answer (score 0):

In java, to read from application.conf in play 2.5, you should inject configuration in your controller as below:

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {
private Configuration configuration;

@Inject
public HomeController(Configuration configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

public Result index() {
    String value = configuration.getString("key");
    System.out.println("value of key is " + key);
    return ok(value);
}
```

}

Because Configuration is a concrete class, binding it in Module class is not needed.

see also this discussion:
[DI for java in play 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634019/play-framework-2-5-1-routing-and-dependency-injection-for-java)