# State not persisted between requests

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a class with the following structure:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

class MyController extends Controller {

  private var myVar = ""

  def stepOne() = Action {
    implicit request => {
      myVar = request.queryString("var").mkString
      Ok(views.html.stepOne())
    }
  }


  def stepTwo() = Action {
    implicit request => {
      println(myVar)
      Ok(views.html.stepTwo())
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that I can call stepOne with some query parameters, they're saved in the class, then I can retrieve them in stepTwo. This class is only used in testing, to mock out certain functionality.

The problem is `myVar` is not stored, when I print out `myVar` in step two, it is still an empty string (I can print it out in step one and it's the correct, non-empty value). What is going on?

Comment: This question should provide some clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863486/is-each-play-framework-web-request-handled-with-a-new-dependency-injected-contro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just annotate controller as `@Singleton`.